# Как проверить поле типа sql_variant на пустоту

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица содержащая поле типа `sql_variant`. Во всех записях таблицы поле не `NULL`. Проверка на пустую строку ничего не дает. Функция `LEN()` не принимает поля типа `sql_variant` в качестве параметра.

Таблица содержит атрибуты произвольных типов данных, поэтому определить на вид какой именно тип данных там ожидается по виду незаполненного поля в результатах запроса невозможно, это может быть что угодно. NULL-значения всегда показаны явно, с ними проблемы нет. Проблема собственно при прямом запросе вроде:

```
select * from tbl where variantField <> ''
```

Даже при условии, что предположительно в интересующих меня записях должны быть строки.

Как еще можно проверить что данное поле пустое, при условии что оно не `NULL`?

Поиск по EnSO пока ничего дал, хотя может плохо искал.

**UPD Похоже это был глюк сервера, тот же самый скрипт, который вчера работал не верно, отработал без проблем с ожидаемыми результатами**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что значит

> поле пустое, при условии что оно не NULL

Думаю, что исходить надо из того, какие данные хранятся в этом поле, и что принять за *"пустое"*.

Смотрите. Пусть, например, есть данные:

```
declare @varData table (id int, value sql_variant);

insert into @varData values (1, 1);
insert into @varData values (2, 'AAAA');
insert into @varData values (3, 0.26);
insert into @varData values (4, 0x);
insert into @varData values (5, getdate());
insert into @varData values (6, '');
insert into @varData values (7, newid());
insert into @varData values (8, N'     ');
insert into @varData values (9, 0x0000);
```

Если иметь ввиду "пустое, но не NULL" в том смысле, что длина элемента составляет 0 байт, то наиболее близкой по смыслу будет функция [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173486.aspx). Запрос

```
select * from @varData where datalength(value) = 0
```

вернёт строки с `id = 4` и `id = 6`.

Строки, у которых значение поля - пустая (в ANSI-SQL смысле) строка, вернёт запрос

```
select * from @varData where value = ''
```

В данном случае строка с `id = 4` не возвращается (хоть значение поля `value` и пустое в смысле `datalength` критерия), а возвращаются строки с `id = 6` (что логично) и `id = 8` (что логично с точки зрения ANSI-SQL, но может быть несколько неожиданно с точки зрения, например C#, где эта же строка не пустая, хоть и составлена из white-space символов).

Строки, у которых значение поля - пустая (опять же в ANSI-SQL смысле) последовательность байт, вернёт запрос

```
select * from @varData where value = 0x
```

В данном случае не возвращается строка с `id = 6` (хотя её `value` пусто в смысле `datalength` критерия), а возвращаются строки с `id = 4` (что логично) и `id = 9` (что опять же может быть несколько неожиданно с точки зрения C#, где массив байт 0x0000 ну никак не пустой).

В общем, выбирайте критерий, исходя из того, что требуется по задаче и согласно данным.

p.s. а вообще для пустоты лучше NULL использовать

Comment: про NULL для пустоты - полностью согласен, но тут уж что есть, с тем и приходится работать. Вероятность корректировки БД близка к нулю, слишком много на нее уже завязано. А за `DATALENGTH` спасибо, завтра попробую.